# can't see my hdd or ssd on instalation

Tags: system-installation, ssd

i can't see any of my hard drivers on the installation, but when I run **gparted** they are both there.

How can I see then on installation or install from live boot via terminal?

Comment: was your request computer an XPS by any chance? or a DELL?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the ex_fat libraries are not installed.  Make sure you do this.  Hopefully this can be installed by default by eOS on the next version.

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse
sudo apt install exfat-utils
```

Comment: That was going to be my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a guess here, but i can assume its the root cause.

In case your laptop configures your disk as RAID you need to switch it to AHCI in your BIOS setup.

Just go to your bios and look it up, or search the net for your laptop model to see the default configuration. if its Dell XPS i can tell you right now that its configured as RAID.

Comment: Indeed it is necessary to do this action on almost all Dell XPS bought with a Windows

Answer (score 1):

Check under your BIOS to make sure you have no RAID settings or its set as IDE. this has caused me many hours of issues in the past

Answer (score 0):

Without any further detail I can only assume these "missing" hard drives are not the ones elementary is installed on correct? Being that they are showing in in gparted leads me to believe that they just are being mounted.

[This link my shed a little light on your issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)